# How to improve my simulation of 3d space in pygame?

Tags: python, 3d, pygame, projection, perspective

As for my previous question, I'm trying to simulate a 3d space in pygame. So far, I came up with a very simple idea that uses the third coordenate as a denominator to 'compress' (pretty sure there's some terminology here I'm not aware of) the furthest points around the center of the screen and reduce their sizes.

Could anyone suggest a simple improvement to this idea? I feel like I can just tune that denominator used for the projection (see the code) to create a way more accurate simulation.

If you run the code bellow you'll have a not-that-bad simulation of (let's say) a spaceship passing by some stars (pressing w or s). They dissapear if they get to far and a new one is created after that. But, if I apply a rotation (a or d), it becomes obvious that the simulation is not doing well, as I'm not really projecting the 3d points onto the 2d screen.

```
import pygame
import random
import numpy as np

pygame.init()
run=True

#screensize
screensize = (width,height)=(600,600)
center=(int(width/2),int(height/2))
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screensize)

#delta mov
ds=0.1
do=0.0001

#Stars
points=[]
for i in range(1000):
    n1 = random.randrange(-5000,5000)
    n2 = random.randrange(-5000,5000)
    n3 = random.randrange(-30,30)
    points.append([n1,n2,n3])

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run=False

    ################## keys
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        for p in points:
            p[2]-=ds
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        for p in points:
            p[2]+=ds

    if keys[pygame.K_a] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            for p in points:
                p[0]=np.cos(-do)*p[0]-np.sin(-do)*p[2]
                p[2]=np.sin(-do)*p[0]+np.cos(-do)*p[2]
        else:
            for p in points:
                p[0]=np.cos(do)*p[0]-np.sin(do)*p[2]
                p[2]=np.sin(do)*p[0]+np.cos(do)*p[2]


    ###############################projection###################

    for p in points:
        #this is to create new stars
        if p[2]<=-30 or p[2]>=30:
            p[0] = random.randrange(-5000,5000)
            p[1] = random.randrange(-5000,5000)
            p[2] =30
        else:
            #this is to ignore stars which are behind the ship
            if p[2]<=0:
                pass
            else:
                try:
                    #THIS IS THE PROJECTION I USE, I TAKE THE RADIUS BECAUSE I GUESS I'LL NEED IT... BUT I DON'T USE IT XD
                    r = ((p[0]**2+p[1]**2+p[2]**2)**(1/2))
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,255,0),(int(p[0]/p[2]+center[0]),int(p[1]/p[2]+center[1])),int(10/p[2]))
                #this is to prevent division by cero and alike
                except Exception as e:
                    pass

    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill((0,0,0))


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What you do is not bad at all. In general [perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) is achieved by [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). Your approach is close to that.

Comment: It must be wrong XD when I rotate the scenario it becomes a mess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general perspective is achieved by [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). Your approach is close to that.

I recommend to operate [Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system), where the 3 dimensions have the same scale.
Emulate a [Perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) when you draw the points.
This means you've to calculate the `w` component of the [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) dependent on the depth (z coordiante) of the point (e.g. `w = p[2] * 30 / 5000`) and to perform a "perspective divide" of the `x`, `y` and `z` components by the `w` component, before you draw the points. e.g:

[image]

```py
#delta mov
ds=10
do=0.01

#Stars
points=[]
for i in range(1000):
    n1 = random.randrange(-5000,5000)
    n2 = random.randrange(-5000,5000)
    n3 = random.randrange(-5000,5000)
    points.append([n1,n2,n3])

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run=False

    ################## keys
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        for p in points:
            p[2]-=ds
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        for p in points:
            p[2]+=ds

    if keys[pygame.K_a] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            for p in points:
                p[0], p[2] = np.cos(-do)*p[0]-np.sin(-do)*p[2], np.sin(-do)*p[0]+np.cos(-do)*p[2]
        else:
            for p in points:
                p[0], p[2] = np.cos(do)*p[0]-np.sin(do)*p[2], np.sin(do)*p[0]+np.cos(do)*p[2]

    ###############################projection###################

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for p in points:
        #this is to create new stars
        if p[2]<=-5000 or p[2]>=5000:
            p[0], p[1], p[2] = random.randrange(-5000,5000), random.randrange(-5000,5000), 5000
        else:
            #this is to ignore stars which are behind the ship
            if p[2]<=0:
                pass
            else:
                w = p[2] * 30 / 5000
                pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,255,0),(int(p[0]/w+center[0]),int(p[1]/w+center[1])),int(10/w))

    pygame.display.update()
```

---

Furthermore, the rotation is not correct. When you do

> ```py
> p[0]=np.cos(-do)*p[0]-np.sin(-do)*p[2]
> p[2]=np.sin(-do)*p[0]+np.cos(-do)*p[2]
> ```

the `p[0]` is changed in the first line, but the original value should be used in the 2nd line.
Do "tuple" assignment to solve the issue:

```py
p[0], p[2] = np.cos(-do)*p[0]-np.sin(-do)*p[2], np.sin(-do)*p[0]+np.cos(-do)*p[2]
```